# awk gsub using variable for pattern matching

Tags: linux, awk

`gsub(pattern, replacement, target)`: allows a variable to be used for ***pattern***, but does not let me do regular expression.

`gsub(/pattern/, replacement, target)`: lets me do regular expression, but I cannot use a variable for the ***`pattern`***.

Is there a way to get both variable pattern and regex to work in `gsub`? I'd like to stick with awk, no sed or shell.

Comment: Seeing the latest answer - do you have an example of what exactly you want to do and how it doesn't work?

Comment: thanks, the pattern (re) will be the 2nd parm on the input, used to replace the  1st parm. so looks like: awk 'BEGIN { re = [$2] } { gsub(re, "X", $1); print $1}' <<< '1a2b3c ad'

Answer (score 2):

If you mean something like ruby:

```
/foo#{pat}bar/
```

that's not possible in awk (that way). But you can build the pattern when calling gsub.

```
pat = "[a-z]+"
gsub("foo" pat "bar", rep, target)
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use a variable containing a regular expression:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { re = "[abc]" } { gsub(re, "X"); print }' <<< '1a2b3c'
1X2X3X
```

But the quoting can get complicated, see [Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) in the gawk manual.